# Add custom product attribute to URL product view

Tags: url-rewrite, product-view, ce-1.9.2.2, product-urls

I have created an EAV entity (that represents the brand) which can be associated to a product as an attribute.
Now, I would like to add the name of the brand to the product view URL.
I would like something like this:

```
http://myhost.com/category-name/brand-name/product-name
```

Is there a way to extend the url rewrite for products view?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create url key with "/" sign you need to override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url`'s `formatUrlKey()` method.
You can do it like so:

```
class Vendor_Module_Model_Catalog_Product_Url extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url
{
    /**
     * Format Key for URL
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    public function formatUrlKey($str)
    {      
        // added '/' character
        $urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z\/.]+#i', '-', Mage::helper('catalog/product_url')->format($str));      
        $urlKey = strtolower($urlKey);
        $urlKey = trim($urlKey, '-');

        return $urlKey;
    }

}
```

You can override `beforeSave()` method of the Backend Model of Catalog Product Urlkey attribute as following:

```
class Vendor_Module_Model_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey 
{
    /**
     * Before save
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
     * @overridden
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();

        $urlKey = $object->getData($attributeName);
        if ($urlKey == '') {
            $urlKey = "{$object->getBrandName()}/{$object->getName()}";
        }
        $object->setData($attributeName, $object->formatUrlKey($urlKey));

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Now while product is being saved, if url key empty it will automatically create an 'brand-name/name' like url. If it comes to category name it is a matter of magento configuration to or not to add category name at the begining of URL address.

---

Alternatively check out this free extension, it does exactly what you require:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-product-urls-seo.html